# Multi value field sql query, check if value exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I do have a problem with a query. I spend hours trying to find a way to make it work but I can't :( Even if it feels easy !

Let's say I have this table:

```
entity_id    delta    name
----------------------------
1            0        speaker
1            1        screen
2            0        mouse
2            1        TV
2            2        tablet
```

I simply want to return the entity id of a content where name != 'speaker' (in this example, it would be entity_id = 2).

If I use "name LIKE 'speaker'", it returns me entity 1. But I want the other way. So I try to use "name NOT LIKE 'test'", it returns me all the other rows, which is normal, but I would like to only get entity_id 2.

I feel like I am missing something easy.

Thanks for you help !

Ed

Comment: I'm find difficult to understand, can you please formulate an example?

Comment: I tried to correct a few sentences and use different names. Is it better?

Comment: but in your second row, "screen" has entity_id "1". So, that's NOT "speaker", but still "1" (???)

Comment: See answer from @juergen d, it is a multi field value so multiple rows can be linked to the same content. Sorry I wasn't clear enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select entity_id
from your_table
group by entity_id
having sum(name = 'test') = 0
```

Comment: Works great ! Thanks a lot :)